# Returning IEnumerable with "ToListAsync()" inside the method

Tags: c#, .net

Currently I am working with some one else's code. And this is not the first time when I see something like this:

```
public async MyMethod Task<IEnumerable<MyResult>> FindResults()
{
// some code here
var ret = await repository.BusinessObjects.ToListAsync()

return ret;

}
```

my **question** is: Isn't it counterproductive to use **IEnumerable** in MyMethod return type because the result has been enumerated already and it's better to keep it this way? Wouldn't it be better to use **List** ?

(I guess it also applies to non-async operations, but I decided to show this the way I see it in the code I working with just in case)

Comment: Consider reading this get idea about what `IList`, `IEnumerable` and `ICollection` http://www.claudiobernasconi.ch/2013/07/22/when-to-use-ienumerable-icollection-ilist-and-list/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically speaking there is no problem with writing code this way. In your specific code example above it does not matter (technically) if you are returning a `List<>` instance but the method's return type is `IEnumerable<>`. There is no performance hit, the actual returned type is still a `List<>`.

That being said it is not good practice. There is a design guideline that states you should structure your methods to always return the most specific type possible **AND** accept the most generic/abstract type possible (*within limitations of course, you should not take object as a parameter for each method*).

See this article titled [Return the most specific type, accept the most generic type](http://Return%20the%20most%20specific%20type,%20accept%20the%20most%20generic%20type) by Vladimir Khorikov as a reference. This has also been asked on SO before, see [Is it better to return the most specific or most general type from an action method?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3434385/1260204).

So this would mean the following 2 signatures would be good practice (using your example) assuming that the 1st signature a `List<MyResult>` is the actual returned type and in the 2nd example that whatever is doing the updating just needs to iterate over the input.

```
public async Task<List<MyResult>> FindResultsAsync();
public async Task UpdateAsync(IEnumerable<MyResult> itemsForUpdate);
```

Comment: Agree in principle, but not to the extent of returning a `List<T>`, since this will prevent you from altering your method definition to return a different collection type (such as `ObservableCollection<T>`) without breaking consumers. It's better practice to return `IList<T>` (or `ICollection<T>`) instead.

Comment: @Douglas - I think we are both in agreement. If it is possible for a method signature (via interface or other type) to return something else  like (using your example) `ObservableCollection<>` then you are 100% correct, an `IList<>` would be the best return type choice because it is the most specific type between `ObservableCollection<>` and `List<>` (if that were the other possibility). So the principle above would still be valid. Also I think that many times interfaces would always be the better return type choice over concrete types so that implementations can remain flexible.

Comment: If it is known that the implementation will never change and the return type will always be static then the return type itself, in most cases, would be the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your use case. IEnumerable provides a better abstraction but it definitely can come with performance costs depending on your use.

Its true that you would iterate once to create the list async and (potentially) iterate again as a consumer of the enumerable.

I personally (for my use case) use the pattern you showed only in non performance critical paths e.g. initialization

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't it counterproductive to use `IEnumerable` in `MyMethod` return type because the result has been enumerated already and it's better to keep it this way? Wouldn't it be better to use `List` ?

I don't see how it would make any difference or why it's a problem. Usually the problem is when you return a lazy collection (like an EF query), where multiple iterations on it result in multiple database calls.

You are returning a `List`, and so multiple iterations are not a concern.  If you *wanted* to return `List` to make it clear to the caller that it's safe to iterate multiple times that's fine, but it really doesn't change anything.

There are *other* benefits to returning a more base type (e.g. it allows you to return different collection types other than `List`) but in the context of your concern about multiple enumerations, whether the return type is `List` or `IEnumerable` doesn't matter.

Comment: using `IEnumerable` the interface doesn't contain `Add()` or `Remove()` method. Ensuring that you collection will not be changed while passing between multiple layers. 

In both `List` or `IEnumerable` the query is already materialized. Just returning the lowest interface isn't a good thing ? If my Method returning `IList` i can return `List` or `Array`. If we are returning List<T> then it we are programming to implementation rather implementation.

Comment: @Eldho True, that would change what the client could do with the returned collection, but I think the OP's concern was not that as much as enumerating multiple times, which isn't a huge concern with `List`.

Comment: Yes in that context List should be the best bet

Comment: @Eldho To be clear, I'm not saying that returning `List` is better; I'm saying that from that point of view (multiple iterations) _it doesn't matter_.  There are _other_ benefits to returning a more base type but they don't apply to the concerns in the question.  I'll add that to my answer so it's more clear.

Comment: Thanks , i get little biased.