# How does the Liskov Substitution Principle apply to function return types?

Tags: solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

The Liskov Substitution Principle states that:

> Objects in a program should be replaceable with instances of their sub-types without altering the correctness of that program.

Assuming that:

```
interface Iterable<T> {
    fun getIterator(): Iterator<T>
}

interface Collection<T> : Iterable<T> {
    val size: Int
}

interface List<T> : Collection<T> {
    fun get(index: Int): T
}

interface MutableList<T> : List<T> {
    fun set(index: Int, item: T): Unit
}
```

When LSP is applied to input parameters, the lowest-level abstraction should be applied:

**DO**

```
fun foo(items: Iterable<Any>) { ... }
```

**DON'T**

```
fun foo(items: List<Any>) { ... }
```

But, does LSP apply to function return types, and if so, does the reverse apply?

```
fun bar(): Iterable<Any> { ... }
```

**OR**

```
fun bar(): List<Any> { ... }
```

Comment: That's the DIP, rather than the LSP; you're programming to the abstraction. You could also read about co- and contra-variance, e.g. in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it better to return the most specific or most general type from an action method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434367/is-it-better-to-return-the-most-specific-or-most-general-type-from-an-action-met)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and yes. In order to comply with the LSP, argument types in an overriding method must be *contravariant*, as you point out. The reverse is true for the return type -- this must be *covariant*, i.e. of the same type, or a more specific type, as the return type in the method being overidden.

Think of the slogan "demand no more, promise no less." Let's say the superclass method returns a Rectangle. This method can be overidden to return a Square, as this "promises more," but not to return a Shape, as this would "promise less."